# How to use EJB3 in Webservice

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

I created a EJB project in eclipse id, the project is to retrieve data from a database and write data to the database. I did that database handling part using JPA. Now I want to convert this to a web service. I googled for two days but every guide stuck me some where with lot of questions. 
  Some of the tutorials said just add @webservice, @webmethod annotations to the Stateless bean class, but then eclipse gives error even without deploying. Please someone help me to move forward.

Thank you.
Isuru

Comment: But why you using EJB if you need to make it a WS? Because EJB itself a distributed component.  Rather than make a simple DAO class to handle the DB operation, make one service to handle the operations and publish that service as Webservice. Eclipse provide plugin to create a WS from any POJO class. It will generate the WSDL as well when you deploy the code.

Comment: @Paarth it's quite legitimate to expose a WS interface from an Stateless Session Bean. I agree it's not the only way, but what Isuru is trying should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed enough to just add the annotation:

```
@Stateless
@WebServicepublic 
class MySessionBean {  
  public void doSomething() { … }
}
```

By default, all public methods are exposed to the web service. If you want to limit it, you have to add @Webmethod to all methods which should be exposed.

Besides that, you should tell us which errors you get.

Answer (score 0):

For me Eclipse does not complain about this:

```
package ord.djna.ejb;
import javax.ejb.Local;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@Local
@WebService
public interface TheFacadeLocal {

    int countItems();

}
```

Please show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download Eclipse for Java EE and create new project just with a stateless session bean. See if the annotations work, I guess its a problem with your 'java build path' settings in eclipse.